# Confuse with nginx proxy location

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have two proxy location settings.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain;
    charset utf-8;
    return 307 https://$server_name$request_uri; 
} 
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    charset utf-8;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain;
    location /OPQ/api {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6666/v1/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /OPQ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6666;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Expect the results：

http://domain/OPQ/v1/Login -> http://127.0.0.1:6666/v1/Login

http://domain/OPQ/api?abc=1234 -> http://127.0.0.1:6666/v1/api?abc=1234

Actual results:

http://domain/OPQ/v1/Login -> 404 Error

http://domain/OPQ/api?abc=1234 -> http://127.0.0.1:6666/v1/api?abc=1234

I have tested the `http://127.0.0.1:6666/v1/Login`, it works fine.

This makes me confused. Why the `OPQ/api` setting as I expected and the other not so. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `proxy_pass` statement contains two components, (1) the protocol & address of the service, and (2) an optional URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

In your second case, there is no optional URI, so the requested URI is not changed. The URI `/OPQ/foo` is sent upstream as `/OPQ/foo`.

You need to replace `/OPQ/` with `/`, this is achieved by adding a trailing `/` to both the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements.

For example:

```
location /OPQ/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6666/;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried to replace the setting as you said. But it still not work. When I use the `http://domain/OPQ/v1/Login` to access. The request URL would change to `http://domain/v1/Login` automatically and got 404 error again.